# Trying to have a normalized database of trading cards

Tags: database-normalization

I've been looking over data normalization and don't quite see how to apply it to the database of cards im setting up. Each card is from a set and that set has a symbol. Since those two things will be the same for each card in that set should that make up it's own table? Should all the cards be in one large table regardless of set?

Also, is there a reason not to just have cards from each set in a table named after the symbol and just put the name of the set in a column?

I'm a noob to this so if i need to be more specific or just shut face let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I think I got it figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what normal form you want.

Consider a card table that looks like this, the primary key is `(Name, Set)`:

```
Card:
| Name   | Set   | Symbol |
---------------------------
| Card 1 | Set 1 | 1      |
| Card 2 | Set 1 | 1      |
| Card 3 | Set 1 | 1      |
| Card 1 | Set 2 | 2      |
| Card 2 | Set 2 | 2      |
```

This table is in [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) (1NF). However it is not in [Second Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form) (2NF), because the value of `Symbol` is dependant on the value of `Set`, and `(Set)` is a proper subset of the primary key.

As you said in your question, if you want 2NF, you need to create a seperate `Set` table:

```
Card:
| Name   | Set   |
------------------
| Card 1 | Set 1 |
| Card 2 | Set 1 |
| Card 3 | Set 1 |
| Card 1 | Set 2 |
| Card 2 | Set 2 |

Set:
| Name  | Symbol |
------------------
| Set 1 | 1      |
| Set 2 | 2      |
```

These tables are now both in 2NF (and 3NF, BCNF, 4NF, ...).

As to the second part of your question, the reason you would do this instead of having all the columns in one table are twofold:

- **To make changes easier.** If you want to change the attributes of a set, you only have to update one row in the `Set` table, instead of updating all the cards in that set.
- **To reduce the possibility of data corruption.** There is a real dependency between set and symbol, but the first table does not enforce this. This means the database will happily allow you to get into a corrupt state where cards in the same set have different symbols. In the second set of tables, this can't happen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your problem, but if I wanted to set up a databased TCG, I'd have one table with all the cards and the corresponding information. I'll just assume the YGO cards for this, because they are somewhat well known.

In the 'cards' table, you'd have an auto-increment 'CardID', the name of the card, the description of the card, the symbol of the card, the effect ID, the level, the attack value and the defence value. All those things are 'card-related'.

The sets themselves are in a 1:1 table, which link any number of cards to the player ID.

So assuming that Player ataylor has three Blue-Eyes White Dragon in his set, he'd have three entries in that table, all having the same Card/Player-Combination...each of them representing one of the cards.

Is that what you wanted to know?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question either, but I would recommend you keep all the cards in one big table, and not split them out into different tables for different sets.

What you'd want would be an Id (cardId) to uniquely identify that card. Then have a setId and a symbolId.

Then your card table would look something like:

CardId,SetId,SymbolId,Description

1 , 1 , 2, An awesome card

2 , 2 , 2, Another Sweet card

---

You can make that table massive and be able to count up / separate out cards of any set or symbol super fast.
You'll then just need a look up table to tell you what SetId 1 is and what 2 is.